# JSON API not showing full content

Tags: json, plugin-json-api

I am trying to create a Windows Store App using [IdeaPress](https://github.com/ideanotion/ideapress/issues), which relies on the [JSON API Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/). Unfortunately requesting recent_posts returns just content up to the

```
<!--more-->
```

tag. I'd like to display the whole post, though. Any ideas on how to do this?

[This](http://wp7app.de/api/get_recent_posts/?dev=1) is my json code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to show the full post content only in the JSON API:

```
function remove_more_wpse_96740($content) {
    if(get_query_var('json')){
        global $post;
        $content = preg_replace('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/','',$post->post_content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_more_wpse_96740',1);
```

by targeting the `json` query variable and remove the `<!--more-->` part of the post.

If you have a custom string like `<!--more But wait, there's more! -->`, it will also be removed.

This part of the plugin in `/json-api/models/post.php`:

```
  function set_content_value() {
    global $json_api;
    if ($json_api->include_value('content')) {
      $content = get_the_content($json_api->query->read_more);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      $this->content = $content;
    } else {
      unset($this->content);
    }
  }
```

is fetching the content and the check for `<!--more(.*?)?-->` in the content takes place in the WordPress function `get_the_content()`.

**PS:** Using the method above will disable `<!--noteaser-->` in the JSON API, but that should be alright since you want the full post content there.

Comment: get_query_var('json') should be changed to get_query_var('json_route'), as otherwise it won't work any more!

Comment: Worked great for me but had to change `get_query_var('json')` to `get_query_var('json_route')`